# Is [nested] a meta tag?

Tags: discussion, meta-tags

Sorry, no puns today. I'm after some discussion rather than a burnination.

I suspect the tag [nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested) doesn't make sense by itself, without being combined with some other tag. From the tag wiki:

> This tag relates to any of various nested entities in programming,
>   including but not limited  to:
>
> - Nested data structures
> - Nested queries
> - Nested calls to a procedure, subroutine, method or operation
>
> For example, nesting queries in SQL means to create a subquery. Its
>   result is used in the query itself and provides a query order and
>   subsets.
>
> **See also**
>
> - [recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive)
> - [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursion)

By contrast, the tag [nested-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-queries) makes sense without having to be combined with another tag.

"The Death of Meta Tags" seems to suggest that if a tag doesn't make sense by itself, it's a meta tag:

> Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually
>   call dependent tags. These are tags that don't say anything by
>   themselves - you can't tell what the question is about unless they're
>   paired with some other tag (or several of them). These tags are a
>   problem because people don't realize this and will often use that as
>   the question's only tag.

Is "nested" a meta tag?

Comment: Hmm, no, not a meta tag.  Just a hapless user that tried to tag with "nested class" or "nested loops", etcetera.  Using a space instead of a dash.  The post editor is partly responsible, it doesn't re-arrange the tags until *after* the question is submitted.  Clumsy tagging doesn't necessarily mean the question is clumsy.  Although it is a pretty good selector, reactivating thousands of them does more harm than good.  Just fix it when you run into such a question.